# Callback function on jquery validation engine not working as expected

Tags: jquery, json, callback

I'm using the jQuery ValidationEngine plugin to validate a form; the validation per se works well, however when done, it puts a JSON string on the screen, rather than redirecting to the previous page as expected. Here's the code I'm using:

Call of the validation engine:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#newForm").validationEngine('attach', {
            ajaxFormValidation: true,
            onAjaxFormComplete: urlValidationCallback,
            onBeforeAjaxFormValidation: deleteAllPrompts
        });
    });
</script>

function urlValidationCallback(status, form, json, options){

    if (status === true) {
        goToURL(json[0][2]);
    }
}

function formSubmit(){
...
if ($success) {           
      $successArray = array();
      array_push($successArray, 'newForm');
      array_push($successArray, true);
      array_push($successArray, "/albums/view/" . $album->id);
      array_push($arrayToJs, $successArray);
   }
echo json_encode($arrayToJs);
}
```

But instead of loading "/albums/view/...", the screen goes blank and displays the following:

```
[["newForm",true,"\/albums\/view\/13"]]
```

Can someone please point me to where the problem lies ?

Thanks very much

Comment: When does `formSubmit` gets called?

Comment: @ShankarSangoli formSubmit is called when the form is being submitted, i.e. via the form's action attribute, the method being post.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is shown by jQuery Validation engine when you have an error, syntax or else in your javascript. in your beforeCall or in your ajaxValidationCallback.

Since you see the json, the call was successfull but then during the callback something went wrong in your javascript that made the return to the calling page impossible.

Check your browser javascript console for errors.